# Machlokes Hatanaim when Kriat Shema should be said

Tags: zemanim, shema, mishna, machlokes, tractate-brachot

The first Blat of Berachot tells us about a Mahlokes when Krias Shema should be recited. There are almost 10 shitos there.

What is the Machlokes-is there a Sevara for each shita?

For instance, the Shita that says it's from the time the Kohen dips when he's not pure?

Comment: This question is a little broad. Maybe ask for just one Tanna?

Comment: You could always ask more than one question, if you want.

Comment: Yes, but most of them make sense....for instance, this one about broadness -- it would take a lot of work to answer for all the shitos there, no?

Comment: Check out the [help center](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help) and [frequently asked questions](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) for more info.

Comment: (: the more the better. I fixed it!

Comment: @Shokhet I think it's okay. I mean, there are only a handful or two of views in the _mishna_: it's not like the question is seeking the reason for every _shita_ in every _machlokes_ in _shas_.

Comment: @msh210 That was a response to the [first revision](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/e53c9b03-1cc4-4e39-9105-dd2f16ebad4c/view-source), not the current one.

Comment: @Shokhet I don't see the difference.

Comment: @msh210 "*There is almost 10 shitos there..What is the Machlokes-is there a Sevara for each Tanna?*" (from the [first revision](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/47528/1))

Comment: Argue about the Answer that's more important! (:

Comment: @Shokhet and now it says "There are almost 10 shitos there. What is the Machlokes-is there a Sevara for each shita?". The grammar is better, but the only substantive difference I see is that it now asks for the _s'vara_ for everyone's _shitos_, not only _tanaim_'s _shitos_. Am I missing something?

Comment: @msh210 I thought that the last line of the current revision limits the question only to one opinion.

Comment: @Shokhet "For instance" means that that's an example: it doesn't limit the question to that example.

Comment: @msh210 If that's the case, then I still think it's too broad -- this could be [book sized](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

In his commentary to Berachot 2b [R. Solomon Ben Aderet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_ibn_Aderet) cites [R. Hai Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hai_Gaon) as providing explanations for some of the views:

- **R. Eliezer**

  He holds that the time for reciting Shema is the beginning of sunset, based on a different interpretation of the verse that the Talmud cited as referring to *tzeit hakochavim*.

  > דרבי אליעזר דאמר משעה שקדש היום סבר ובא השמש ביאת שמשו דהיינו תחלת השקיעה ומאי וטהר טהר גברא
- **R. Yehoshua**

  He holds that the time for reciting Shema is *tzeit hakochavim*, based on interpreting the same verse the way the Talmud originally interpreted it.

  > ור' יהושע סבר ביאת אורו הוא ומאי וטהר טהר יומא
- **R. Chanina**

  He holds that the time for reciting Shema is not dependent on when night begins, but on when is considered the time of lying down. His view is that people don't lie down in the beginning of the night; they don't lie down until the time that the poor eat their bread after speaking with the neighbors.

  > ור' חנינא אמר דלא תלינן שיעורא בתחלת הלילה אלא שעת שכיבה ואין דרכן של בני אדם לישכב בתחלת הלילה אלא משעה שהעני נכנס לאכול פתו לאחר שמספר עם שכניו
- **R. Acha**

  He holds that the time for lying down is even later than R. Chanina's view, when people come in for their meal, because in the beginning of the night they speak with each other in the city streets by their doors.

  > ורבי אחא משעה שבני אדם נכנסין להסב שהוא מאוחר יותר לפי שמספרין בתחלת הלילה ברחוב העיר על פתחיהן זה עם זה

However, this doesn't address the opinions of R. Meir and R. Yehuda. The Talmud ends up clarifying that the time according to R. Meir is only moments before *tzeit hakochavim*, and [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) explains that therefore it is still considered the time of lying down:

> בין השמשות דר' יהודה מהלך חצי מיל לפני צאת הכוכבים ודרבי יוסי כהרף עין לפני צאת הכוכבים ורבי מאיר כרבי יוסי ס"ל וכי טביל מקמי הכי סמוך לחשכה הוא וזמן שכיבה קרינן ביה

It would seem that according to Rashi the entire dispute may be over what the time of lying down is (whereas according to R. Hai Gaon it sounds like some of the tannaim focus on when night begins).

[Tosafot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot) states that R. Yehuda does not subscribe to the general exposition that the verse ובשכבך means that Shema is to be recited at the time of lying down; thus, R Yehuda's view sets the time for *Ma'ariv* (and presumably Shema) much earlier at *plag haminchah*:

> תימא תיקשי ליה לנפשיה שהרי פלג המנחה מבעוד יום היא והוא אומר מיד כשיעבור פלג המנחה הוי זמן תפלת ערבית ויש לומר דלדידיה לא קשיא דלא דריש בשכבך ובקומך אבל לרבנן דדרשי קשיא דאינו זמן שכיבה

[R. Jacob Joshua Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joshua_Falk) objects to the idea that the tannaim are actually disagreeing about the fundamental nature of the time for Shema. In his opinion (hesitatingly offered against the earlier authorities) it is unreasonable to assume that they're all disputing when the time for lying down is. There are really only three possibilities:

1. Each person has their own time based on when they lie down.
2. We follow the time that the majority of people lie down.
3. Once the first person lies down it is the time of lying down.

Since there are no other possibilities and it would be strange for the tannaim to be debating the reality of when people actually lie down, they must all agree as to the essential biblical level law (which is that Shema is recited at the time of lying down which is determined via one of the above three methods). Rather, they are debating the rabbinic decrees surrounding the recitation of Shema. Because the Sages didn't want to burden the congregation they needed to set a time for everyone before they ate. Thus, the difference of opinion is whether that time is when kohanim eat, when the poor eat, or when the regular people eat, etc.

> וכל זה כתבתי לשיטת הגאון ולולי שאיני כדאי היה נראה לי לפרש בדרך אחר משום שנראה לי דוחק גדול לומר דכל הני תנאי פליגי בזמן ק"ש דאורייתא דלכאורה אין לספק בזמן שכיבה דאורייתא אלא באחד משלשה פנים או שנאמר דכל חד וחד קודם שכיבה שלו או דהכל תלוי בשכיבה לרוב בני אדם או דמיד משיתחיל זמן שכיבה לשום אדם מתחיל זמן ק"ש כדקי"ל זריזין מקדימין למצות א"כ ממילא תו אי אפשר לפרש להעמיד מחלוקת דכל הני תנאי בשיעורי טובא שאין טעם לדבר שיחלוקו במציאות לכך היה נראה לי לפרש דכל הני תנאי לאו בשיעורא דאורייתא פליגי דמדאורייתא בודאי ליכא אלא באחד מג' פנים שזכרנו מיהו לעולם פשטא דקרא דסמוך לשכיבה בעינן היינו אחר זמן אכילה דהוה ביממא כדאיתא ביומא אלא דכל הנך תנאי דפליגי בשיעורא דזמן ק"ש היינו בשיעורא דרבנן קמיפלגי א' שתקנו תפלת ערבית ועשו ג"כ סייג לדבריהם שלא יאכל קודם שיתפלל ותקנו ג"כ להסמיך ק"ש לתפלה שיהא קריאתו בציבור או משום ברוב עם הדרת מלך ומשום טורח הציבור הוצרכו לקבוע זמן מיוחד לכולם שיהא קודם זמן אכילה לכל חד כדאית ליה מר באכילת כהנים ומר באכילת עניים ואין בזה עקירת דבר מן התורה היינו כדפרישית במתני' דק"ש שעל המטה עיקר כדפרישית לעיל בלשון רש"י וגם התוס' מודים דיוצא בזה